# Prevent powershell from grouping results from json

Tags: json, powershell

I'm parsing json files and the process is doing what I'm expecting to, with one exception: it is returning results as grouped together when I want them split up by rows.

What I'm trying to get is a list of errors from a file

```
$json = '{
"building": [
    {
        "buildingname": "NAPA Auto Parts",
        "files": [{
                "sheets": [{
                        "name": "BATTERY",
                        "results": [{
                                "filename": "BATTERY - 1679568711.xlsx",
                                "sku": "1679568711"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "name": "2.15.19.xlsx",
                "status": "processed",
                "fileId": "c586bba6-4382-42c4-9c29-bffc6f7fe0b6"
            }, {
                "name": "Oct-Nov 2018 11.30.18.xlsx",
                "errors": ["Unknown sheet name: TOILET PLUNGER"],
                "status": "failed",
                "fileId": "afa7c43f-26dc-421c-b2eb-45ad1e899c42"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "buildingname": "O''Reily Auto Parts",
        "files": [{
                "sheets": [{
                        "name": "ALTERNATOR",
                        "results": [{
                                "filename": "ALTERNATOR - 6.3.19 1629453444.xlsx",
                                "sku": "1629453444"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "name": "OIL FILTER",
                        "results": [{
                                "filename": "OIL FILTER - 6.3.19 1629453444.xlsx",
                                "sku": "1629453444"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "name": "6.3.19.xlsx",
                "status": "processed",
                "fileId": "647089fe-9592-4e2b-984f-831c4acd4d9c"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}'

$psdata = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json

$psdata.building | Select buildingname, @{Name="errors";E={$_.files | Select -Expand errors}}, @{Name="fileId";E={$_.files | Select -Expand fileId}} | Where-Object {$_.errors -ne $null}
```

I'm getting these results

```
buildingname       errors                             fileId                                                                      
------------       ------                             ------                                                                      
NAPA Auto Parts    Unknown sheet name: TOILET PLUNGER {c586bba6-4382-42c4-9c29-bffc6f7fe0b6, afa7c43f-26dc-421c-b2eb-45ad1e899c42}
```

This is what I'm trying to get

```
buildingname       errors                             fileId                                                                      
------------       ------                             ------                                                                      
NAPA Auto Parts    Unknown sheet name: TOILET PLUNGER afa7c43f-26dc-421c-b2eb-45ad1e899c42
```

How can I prevent powershell from grouping results together?

Comment: If you just want the first file for the FileId property, then you want:

$psdata.building | Select buildingname, @{Name="errors";E={$_.files | Select -Expand errors}}, @{Name="fileId";E={$_.files | Select -Expand fileId -first 1}} | Where-Object {$_.errors -ne $null}

Comment: Looks like I had an error in my results and it is linking the wrong fileId in this instance. The fileId should be afa7c43f-26dc-421c-b2eb-45ad1e899c42 instead of c586bba6-4382-42c4-9c29-bffc6f7fe0b6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, wasn't sure what exactly you were going for,but I see it now. How about looping like this:

```
$psdata.building | foreach-Object {
    foreach ($File in $_.files)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            BuildingName = $_.BuildingName
            Errors = & {if ($File.Errors) {$File.Errors}}
            fileId = $File.fileId
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need to get me in the right direction. Appreciate your help!